# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=1+(a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+a_0)y^2$

Tags: differential-calculus

I have a problem with the following equation,

$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+P_m(x)y^2$

Where $P_m(x)$ is a polynomial function. I have solution for $P_m(x)=x$ using Mathematica, and Prof @Claude Leibovici solved for me the special case when $P_m(x)=x^n$. Regrading to Prof @Claude Leibovici useful answer, I need a much general solution for $P_m(x)=a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+a_0$

The equation can be rewritten by parametrizeing $y=\frac{u}{u'}$ as $u''+P_m(x)u=0$; i want declare that problem i introduced is a simplified form from  such equation!

I need absoulte solution (not approximate) for the case $P_m(x)=a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+a_0$. And its ok if the solution is in special functions (becacuse, actually, its the only way to do it).

Can anyone here help me please?

Thank you guys

Comment: [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: Even for the case $P_3(x) = x^3 + 1$, Maple does not return a closed-form solution.  I doubt that there is one.

Comment: maybe in special functions @RobertIsrael